Type match error from just an unused qualified import
I'm trying to build an app based on gitlib and want to write a little additional function with this type signature: MonadGit r m => m [RefName]. It's the same as gitlib's own listReferences, so I'll be using that as an example:
module Foo where

import Conduit
import Git.Types

listReferences :: MonadGit r m => m [RefName]
listReferences = runConduit $ sourceReferences .| sinkList

This compiles as expected using $ ghc Reference.hs within nix-shell -p 'ghc.withPackages (p: with p; [ gitlib-libgit2 ])'
However, in the same file I also need to use Git.Libgit2 which I do as a qualified import like this:
module Foo where

import Conduit
import Git.Types
import qualified Git.Libgit2               as LG

listReferences :: MonadGit r m => m [RefName]
listReferences = runConduit $ sourceReferences .| sinkList

This no longer compiles, throwing the following error:
$ ghc Reference.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Foo              ( Reference.hs, Reference.o ) [Source file changed]

Reference.hs:7:19: error: [GHC-25897]
    • Couldn't match type ‘r’ with ‘LG.LgRepo’
        arising from a functional dependency between constraints:
          ‘MonadGit LG.LgRepo m’
            arising from a type ambiguity check for
            the type signature for ‘listReferences’ at Reference.hs:7:19-45
          ‘MonadGit r m’
            arising from the type signature for:
                           listReferences :: forall r (m :: * -> *).
                                             MonadGit r m =>
                                             m [RefName] at Reference.hs:7:19-45
      ‘r’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          listReferences :: forall r (m :: * -> *).
                            MonadGit r m =>
                            m [RefName]
        at Reference.hs:7:19-45
    • In the ambiguity check for ‘listReferences’
      To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
      In the type signature:
        listReferences :: MonadGit r m => m [RefName]
  |
7 | listReferences :: MonadGit r m => m [RefName]
  |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

What is even going on here; why is it trying to match the type with some other type that I'm not even using anywhere? (Linter confirms the import is unused.)
How can I solve this issue?

Git.Libgit2 defines a type alias named MonadGit which resolves to a tuple type. I don't know if that could be conflicting with the expected type class?

Here's the "simple" answer: by importing the module Git.Libgit2, qualified or not, you are choosing r ~ LG.LgRepo, so just give GHC what it wants:
listReferences :: (MonadGit LG.LgRepo m) => m [RefName]
listReferences = runConduit $ sourceReferences .| sinkList

This may throw a warning about fragile bindings which you can address by  turning on the MonoLocalBinds extension (which will be turned on anyway, if you use GADTs or TypeFamilies):
{-# LANGUAGE MonoLocalBinds #-}

or address directly by backing out the constraints through the offending instance, which is pretty gross:
import qualified Git.Libgit2 as LG
import qualified Git.Libgit2.Types as LG

listReferences :: (LG.MonadExcept m, MonadUnliftIO m, LG.HasLgRepo m) => m [RefName]
listReferences = runConduit $ sourceReferences .| sinkList

Anyway, the following module should type check:
{-# LANGUAGE GHC2021, MonoLocalBinds #-}

module Foo where

import Conduit
import Git.Types
import qualified Git.Libgit2 as LG

listReferences :: MonadGit LG.LgRepo m => m [RefName]
listReferences = runConduit $ sourceReferences .| sinkList

Here's the longer answer...
This is an odd interaction between the global scope of instances, type dependencies, and ambiguity checks.
In Haskell, instances aren't scoped -- they all float around in the same "global scope for instances".  So, if you work hard enough, you can construct an example where the qualified import of a module introduces a new instance into this global scope that breaks compilation, even if no definitions from the qualified import are actually "used".
In this specific case, the MonadGit class is defined in Git.Types with a functional dependency:
class ... => MonadGit r m | m -> r where

As far as I can tell, it has no instances in the gitlib package, so when GHC tries to type check the signature:
listReferences :: MonadGit r m => m [RefName]

with only Git.Types imported, all it's got to go on is the type class.  Now, without the functional dependency, this type signature would be ambiguous because the type r appears in a constraint but not in any of the "visible" types that follow.  However, because of the functional dependency m -> r, GHC concludes that this type is not ambiguous, since -- after you call listReferences at a specific m, the functional dependency will determine the correct r.
However, when you add the the qualified import of Git.Libgit2, it brings the following instance into scope:
instance ... => Git.MonadGit LgRepo m where

Because this instance applies to all m, it obeys the functional dependency in a sort of trivial way -- every choice of m implies that r ~ LgRepo.  So, GHC doesn't have a problem with this instance.
Unfortunately, this does cause a problem with the ambiguity check.  When GHC tries to determine if r is or is not ambiguous, it ends up reasoning that -- because of the new instance in scope which says, through the functional dependency, that for any choice of m, we must have r ~ LgRepo -- the only valid type for r is r ~ LgRepo, so it tries to unify r and LgRepo and ends up throwing a type check error, because r is a "rigid" type that can't be unified that way.
You might think this is a bug or the wrong behavior or that GHC should know better, but it is what it is.
As noted above, the easiest way to address this is to specialize your use of r to LgRepo, which is the only r possible when Git.Libgit2 is part of your program.
